# Jcrop issue if image is resized - Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, jcrop

I am using Jquery UI to resize the image. So if is there any image then user can resize the image using the JQuery UI and then I am using JCrop to crop the image. So the problem is when user resizes the image and then crop the image after image resized then for some reason Jcrop picks the original sized image. Is there any way to tell JCrop to pick the resized image dimensions to crop?
Please see the attached image.

[image]

```
$('img').Jcrop({
    onChange: showPreview,
    onSelect: showPreview,
    setSelect: [100, 100, 50, 50]
});

function showPreview(c) {
    if (parseInt(c.w) > 0) {
        // Show image preview
        var imageObj = $('img')[0];
        var canvas = $("#preview")[0];
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(imageObj, c.x, c.y, c.w, c.h, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        cropWidth = c.w;
        cropHeight = c.h;
    }
}
```

Please check the JsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/mpvPC/106/. As you notice that I have out the width and height on image to get it resized if you remove width and height then it works fine

Comment: You haven't shown us any code, it's more than likely to be a coding issue - is it not?

Comment: This is my code.. But this is not a code issue as JCrop works fine if i dont resize an image but once image gets resized then it just picks the original dimension of the image not the resized.

Comment: got a fiddle to show us as an example?

Comment: Hi @Adjit, Please check the jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/mpvPC/106/. As you can see that i have put width and height on image to get it resized if you remove width and height from image then it workd fine

Comment: not really sure what you are talking about. You saying the crop area isn't being transposed properly?

Comment: @Adjit, If you see the fiddle link. You will notice that if you crop any image then canvas is showing the wrong area because i have resized the image. Jcrop is picking the original height and width of the image but if you remove width and height which i have added in the image then Jcrop works fine. The issue is Jcrop doesn work properly or shows the wrong area of the image in canvas if i resize the image. You can check the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/mpvPC/106/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the solution. I just used trueSize. Please check my code below.

```
$('image').Jcrop({
    onChange: showPreview,
    onSelect: showPreview,
    setSelect: [100, 100, 50, 50],
    trueSize: [originalImageWidth, originalImageHeight] // use Original Image dimensions not resized one
});
```